# Wide charectar in print for some Farsi text, but not others

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, translation, widechar

I'm using [Google Translate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29537590/14055985) to convert some error codes into Farsi with Perl.  Farsi is one such example, I've also found this issue in other languages---but for this discussion I'll stick to the single example:

The translated text of "Geometry data card error" works fine (Example 1) but translating "Appending a default 111 card" (Example 2) gives the "Wide character" error.

Both examples can be run from the terminal, they are just prints.

I've tried the [usual things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42194059/14055985) like these, but to no avail:

```perl
use utf8;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

**Example 1: This works**

```perl
perl -Mutf8 -le 'print "\x{d8}\x{ae}\x{d8}\x{b7}\x{d8}\x{a7}\x{db}\x{8c} \x{da}\x{a9}\x{d8}\x{a7}\x{d8}\x{b1}\x{d8}\x{aa} \x{d8}\x{af}\x{d8}\x{a7}\x{d8}\x{af}\x{d9}\x{87} \x{d9}\x{87}\x{d9}\x{86}\x{d8}\x{af}\x{d8}\x{b3}\x{db}\x{8c}"'
خطای کارت داده هندسی
```

**Example 2: This produces Wide char warnings and prints noise**

```perl
perl -Mutf8 -le 'print "\x{d8}\x{a7}\x{d9}\x{81}\x{d8}\x{b2}\x{d9}\x{88}\x{d8}\x{af}\x{d9}\x{86} \x{db}\x{8c}\x{da}\x{a9} \x{da}\x{a9}\x{d8}\x{a7}\x{d8}\x{b1}\x{d8}\x{aa} \x{d9}\x{be}\x{db}\x{8c}\x{d8}\x{b4}\x{200c}\x{d9}\x{81}\x{d8}\x{b1}\x{d8}\x{b6} 111"'
Wide character in print at -e line 1.
# <terminal noise, not Farsi text>
```

**Using Curl**

If I do the same request with `curl` I get this:

```js
curl 'https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl=fa&hl=fa&dt=t&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&otf=1&ssel=0&tsel=0&tk=xxxx&dt=dj&q=%41%70%70%65%6E%64%69%6E%67%20%61%20%64%65%66%61%75%6C%74%20%31%31%31%20%63%61%72%64'
[[["افزودن یک کارت پیش\u200cفرض 111","Appending a default 111 card",null,null,3,null,null,[[]],[[["982c75c78c6c8e6005ec3a4021a7f785","tea_GrecoIndoEuropeA_en2elfahykakumksq_2021q3.md"]]]]],null,"en",null,null,null,1,[],[["en"],null,[1],["en"]]]
```

Notice the `\u200c` in the JSON output above which is a ["‌Zero Width Non-Joiner"](https://unicode-table.com/en/200C/) unicode char.  When `JSON::from_json` parses the `\u200c` it blows up:

```perl
perl -Mutf8 -MJSON -e 'print from_json("[\"\\u200c\"]")->[0];'
Wide character in print at -e line 1.
```

I can "fix" it like this:

```perl
my $c = $res->content;
$c =~ s/\\u[0-9a-f]{4}//;
my $json = from_json($c);
```

and then the output text is correct (right-to-left):

```
افزودن یک کارت پیشفرض 111
```

**Question: What is going on here?**

- Is this a bug in Perl or a JSON?
- Should `\u200c` be parsed properly in some other way?

Comment: Your first example looks like a bunch of escaped utf-8 bytes, not actual utf-8 encoded text. Your second example mixes that with a escaped Unicode character. Should stick with one or the other style (replace `\x{200c}` with `\xE2\x80\x8C`)

Comment: The `-CO` option will tell perl to encode Unicode text written to stdout as utf-8 and suppress the warning in your one-liner. See perlrun for more.

Comment: I don't think any of your code snippets need the utf8 module; that just tells perl the script is encoded in utf-8 and all yours look like plain ASCII.

Comment: Reading https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro is a good idea; it covers some of this in more detail. In particular see https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro#Perl's-Unicode-Model for your second example.

Comment: @Shawn, replacing `\x{200c} with \xE2\x80\x8C` does fix it!  Is there a perl way to replace it programmatically?   I'll read the perl docs you referenced and see what I come up with, but if you know a quick fix...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of stuff going on here. I think a lot of it, especially in the first two examples, stems from not understanding the difference between perl's two string modes (byte oriented and Unicode codepoint oriented).

Example 1 is a raw byte string holding bytes that happen to be UTF-8 encoded, and are passed through unchanged; as long as the terminal that's displaying the output is expecting UTF-8, they'll be rendered correctly. Example 2 has a 'wide' character (With a value greater than 255), making it a Unicode string, where each character represented by a `\x{NN}` number greater than 127 is a Unicode codepoint that is encoded as multiple bytes in UTF-8. Printing this causes mojibake and a warning because standard output is byte oriented without a translation layer.

As I suggested in a comment, reading `perluniintro` (And the other unicode-related documentation) is a good start for learning how things work.

---

But on to the actual task, extracting text from the JSON returned by your `curl` commands... I'd use `jq` instead if this is for a shell script:

```sh
$ curl ... | jq -r '.[0][0][0]'
افزودن یک کارت پیش‌فرض 111
```

Compare to the equivalent perl one-liner:

```sh
$ curl ... | perl -CS -MJSON -lne 'print from_json($_)->[0][0][0]'
افزودن یک کارت پیش‌فرض 111
```

The `-CS` argument tells perl that standard input, output, and error are all UTF-8 encoded. You could also use `-CO` to make that just standard output, and use `decode_json()` instead, which expects raw UTF-8 encoded bytes instead of a Unicode string.

And in a script instead of a one-liner, using the OO interface to `JSON` and tuning how input strings should be encoded using its methods, plus the `open` pragma (Or `binmode` or an encoding layer for `open`) instead of the `-C` option, is the way to go.

Comment: Look closely and you can see the missing ZWJN between ش‌ف vs شف on the `jq` vs `from_json` versions about 3 glyphs from the left of the Farsi script.  -CS might suppress wide char warnings, but from_json is loosing the ZWJN (\u200c).  However, as you suggest, running from_json from a JSON object with ->utf8() enabled will fix it.

Comment: @KJ7LNW I see it in my actual output when I run it through a hex dump. (Might have been lost in this answer due to copy & paste and/or SO stuff.)

Answer (score 1):

The JSON object needs to have utf8 enabled and it will fix the `\u200c`.  Thanks to @Shawn for pointing me in the right direction:

```perl
my $j = JSON->new;
$j->utf8(1);
my $json = $j->decode($c);
```

Now the JSON-formatted text content like `\u200c` is correctly transliterated to `\xe2\x80\x8c` when returning the JSON hash.